# Insert XML as string into SQL column

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, xml

I have a C# website that I need the ability to insert XML into a database column directly from a form field just as a string. I don't want to extract values from the XML, I simply want to insert the XML as-is as a string.

This currently causes my code to choke.

Code:

```
objParameter.Add(new SqlParameter("@Description", txtDesc.Text.Trim()));
```

Text from form field:

```
<note>
<to>Me</to>
<from>You</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget to buy milk.</body>
</note>
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: It could be [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: 'choke'? What does that mean?

Comment: @marc_s `SqlParameter` tells you what rdbms.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to add the parameter to a command before setting the value like code below

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Description", typeof(string));
```

Comment: Unless OP's code doesn't compile, `objParameter` must be the command's parameter collection, in which case the code will work.

Comment: I have the "SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();" The issue is the characters in the XML can't insert into the SQL column.

Comment: How is column defined in the database?

Comment: The column is set as nvarchar(max)

Comment: nvar should except any string so xml should store properly.  What is the stack Trace (including inner exception).  If you have a exception handler look at e.StackTrace or if you are getting an Pop up window press the copy to clipboard shortcut and paste into notepad.

Comment: The error is "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client"

Comment: The error message is not a standard Net Library Error.  I must be someplace in your code.  Probably in a function in the database since the error indicates "from the client".

Answer (score 0):

More than likely there is a xml data type in the database you are using(sql server, mysql, postgres, oracle).  I realize you posted you did not want to extract data from the xml, but down the road it might be interesting to be able to extract data at the database layer.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

How i understand you need to insert xml data as string in database column.
I write following sample:

```
// xmlData from form
string xmlData = "<note> <to>Me</to> <from>You</from> <heading>Reminder</heading> <body>Don\'t forget to buy milk.</body> </note>";

// this replace is necessary because we need two apostrophe ('') to avoid sql syntax error.
// Also is necessary to filter xml data for SQL Injection
string filteredXmlData = xmlData.Replace("'", "''"); 

string CS= @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\TestProjects\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
SqlConnection sqlCon= new SqlConnection(CS);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO MyTable (MyCol) values (@paramValue)", sqlCon);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@paramValue", filteredXmlData));

sqlCon.Open();
int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlCon.Close();
```

Comment: parameterizing the data protects against sql injection and also allows apostrophes without escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my guess as to what is going on. It could be that Asp.Net Request Validation is not allowing you to post the xml because it sees it as dangerous. You can disable validation but you shouldn't. You could do a couple of things, probably html encoding is your best option:

```
string theXml = "";
if(txtDesc.Text != null)
{
    theXml = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(txtDesc.Text.Trim());
    objParameter.Add(new SqlParameter("@Description", theXml));
}
```

Comment: The error is "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client"

Comment: This is a bad answer, apologies. You would have to use client-side javascript to encode the value before posting back.